# How to treat tiredness?

Tags: 60-seconds

Tired people can't go scavanging or respond to events requiring going outside. It really messes with your game, if everybody ends up tired at.

How to treat the Tired-status? I understand that the recovery is somehow related to just how well they are fed. But feeding tired people daily gets expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience with the game, there is not much you can do about tiredness.

However, having a mutant Mary Jane solves that problem, since she can't get tired and will always return safe from scavenging.

The only way to deal with tired people is to feed them, perhaps not every day, but definitely once per 2 days.

Comment: This does line up with my own experiences. I am, however, still hoping for a bit more detailed anwer to come around.

Comment: This is what the wiki says at http://60seconds.wikia.com/wiki/Tired. I think this is the most detailed any answer will say.